# Jquery fancybox doesnt show - only after page reload

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, fancybox

This is my view:

```
<div id='profile_galery'>       
<ul>
<li class='big'><%=link_to image_tag(@profile.user.get_avatar(:large) ), @profile.user.get_avatar(:very_large), :class => 'fancybox'%></li>
```

and this is my js:

```
$(document).on("ready page:change", function() {
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'elastic'
    });
});
```

When i go to page with image with fancybox class and click on it - there is no fancybox but... html change and page is locked. It seems that fancybox is opened but did not show and blocked everything. When i reload the page - the fancybox works. Whats going on?

Comment: ok i install rails gem fancybox-rails and now it works. I read that fancybox have some problem with turbolinks in rails 4

Comment: Thanks for the tip, using the jquery-turbolinks gem also seems to fix it. Here's a Railscast on the issue: http://railscasts.com/episodes/390-turbolinks

Answer (score 10):

try add obviously `parent` option

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({ parent: "body"});
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on r0ma's answer, this is what worked for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript", 'data-turbolinks-eval'="false">  
  $(document).bind('page:change', function(){
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({ parent: "body"})
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Was with the same problem, installing jquery-turbolinks gem as fatfrog sayed solved it.

[jquery-turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks)

Answer (score 0):

This work for me

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  $(".alert .close").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().hide();
  })
  $('.fancybox').fancybox({ parent: "body"})
})
```